My previous advisor wrote that I'm not creative in his recommendation letter
I was applying to a MSc about a year ago, and I asked my advisor in BSc to write me a Letter of Recommendation. He said Ok.
Later, I found his LoR in the application system by asking one of my friends working in the department, and it turned out that he wrote something like this:

I have quite high expectations and my courses are extremely hard, but he got my courses and asked me to supervise him afterwards which means he tends to challenge himself, but the fact is that he is not that much creative. He is also good with planning, you can plan tasks with him and he will deliver them accordingly. Overall I think he is a good candidate for a graduate program.

I don't think that this is a very good recommendation letter, the thing about "not being creative" seems so detrimental to me, what do you think? Should I use this LoR in future applications? I have no idea that whether this is a good LoR or not.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

First: if I came to know you asked “one of my friends working in department” to reveal confidential information, I would immediately disqualify your application and in fact I would probably look to take administrative action against an employee or faculty in my unit who relayed the contents of a LoR to the candidate without asking for permission to release.  It is IMO completely unethical to ask or pressure someone to disclose confidential material, and it is even worse for someone to agree to disclose such material.
Next, whether you ask or not this person, I can tell you I would refuse to write a LoR for someone who has acted the way you have.  Moreover, I would feel bound to advise colleagues of what you did, and I would explicitly mention in any future LoR your unethical behaviour.
The letter is fine: get used to criticism as it is unlikely that any of us was born on the 8th day of Creation.  However, if I were you, I would not ask this person again for a LoR because your actions reflect extremely poorly on your judgment, and I would fear this person would have to disclose this if they were to know what you did.

Indeed, this is possibly quite a creative way to ruin one's application.

I don't think the OP wants to ask the advisor to replace the letter and I also don't think that OP wants to reveal that he/she knows the content. I understand the question as: Is it a good idea to ask the advisor for letters of recommendation in the future?

@JFabianMeier yup I addressed that in my last paragraph.  As explained, the OP could make their situation much worse if their actions come to light.

@BryanKrause so you're saying op should disclose their behavior to prove that they are actually creative? Oh the turntables ;)

@ZeroTheHero Your last paragraph sounds like you think the OP wants to go the advisor and say something like "You wrote I am not creative in the letter of recommendation, can you correct that?", but I don't think the OP ever had something like this in mind. I think the OP purely asks for future letters of recommendation.

More a comment than an answer to your question but I think a useful supplement. Since many bring up ethics I think the professor wasn't that ethical either (at least according to the details provided here). It might depend on the culture and field but I think that explicitly mentioning that student is not creative is pretty damning and is almost guaranteed to end the chance of any successful application there and then. (It is not just not mentioning creativity but having noticed an explicit absence of it!)
I believe that if you are going to write such a letter that leaves very slim chances of a successful application you should be giving the student a heads up about either the specific criticism you will include or if you think that will not be productive at least a warning that you can't write a strong recommendation letter for them. That way the student can plan accordingly. (Really it seems rather cruel to see them try and fail at every application without alerting them to the fact that your letter is secretly very negative. It also creates a lot of useless work for both you and the student in the application process). If the student still insists on wanting your letter despite your warning you have done your part and can write the honest letter including the criticism.

We have become too accustomed to letters just being glowing. An entirely glowing letter is meaningless, because I have been a graduate student, and I have trained and taught many over the years. I am yet to see these incoming classes of flawless geniuses everyone promises. Ironically, if this student has a good GPA, and especially for a masters program, I would be highly motivated to rank this student well. Sure, they lack creativity, but they are hardworking and reliable. Suddenly the hardworking and reliable part likely rings more true if the letter comes across as genuine.

Sorry, this feels like going way too far on guessing what is going on. The letter is full of praise in all but one point. It looks like an honest appraisal which should support the main message: "Overall I think he is a good candidate for a graduate program." If that is unethical, something is seriously broken in the selection process.

I disagree.  Including a well-balanced assessment that includes a mild criticism reinforces the value of the positive comments.

@everyone I guess ;).  I guess it depends on the position they are applying for. But in my field I would say that there is hardly a more damning thing you can say than someone not being creative. I guess if they are looking for labor in a lab or something you can do without but that is not what a PhD should be about. The job is finding creative solutions. I would prefer a letter that says "very good, very creative, raging dysfunctional alcoholic."
It really puzzled me how they can say "not creative" and "Overall I think he is a good candidate for a graduate program."

@Kvothe the OP is talking about applying to a masters program, not PhD. The objectives of a masters student are quite different, and in many fields simply represents an opportunity to expand their skill set. It is also not helpful for a student whose strong suit may not be independence and creativity to be thrust into a program where that may be the main expectation, that is setting them up to fail.

@R1NaNo, oops did miss it was for a masters and not a PhD. That slightly changes things in that it might be okay to not be creative. Still even for a masters I would probably pick the student that didn't have a letter saying they are not creative. I think even for a MSc it should be the hope that you are preparing the student for a career in Science. And I was not saying write a good letter when you expect them to fail. But tell the student you are not writing a good letter.

@Kvothe where we differ is that I do not believe this is a bad letter. It is an honest one, and frankly a helpful one. The notion that higher education is the realm of the delicate creative is antiquated. There are many areas of employment that require high levels of education and low levels of creativity. Do I particularly care if an electron microscopist is very creative? What about an analytical environmental chemist that has to precisely sample 300 lakes and extract data? Sure, a theoretical physicist, someone making new materials, they definitely should be.

Well, you are not supposed to know the details, what reasons are you going to use to ask him to write again?
He did say some good words for you such as you can deliver tasks.
I think the best possible way is to try to find another one to write you a letter, and request don't count that letter in your application, which may not even be possible.

sarcasm
Yes, I think you should tell your advisor that you saw the letter and then ask for another. This will give your advisor an opportunity to adjust their letter of recommendation to reflect that you not only lack creativity but are also brazenly unethical. I think this will be very valuable for any potential department that you will be joining to be aware of.

I don't think the OP ever intended to say something like this to the advisor.

@JFabianMeier yes, it was my response to the appalling behavior, if I did something similar and breached a confidentiality agreement I would be reprimanded and potentially suspended without pay (pre-tenure it would have gone on my file and may have impacted my career trajectory). My hope was the OP would see this and think long and hard about the situation, because I think that sentence in their recommendation letter is the least of their worries if they are ethically OK with obtaining confidential information as they claim they have.

Considering that the ethics may not be clear to the OP and that the OP looks like a non-native English speaker, sarcasm may not land well at all.

Please mark sarcasm. Both voters and readers might get the wrong impression. Imagine the outcome of following your advice :-D

Please mark sarcasm. - I would say this is especially true on a public site with a wide variety of users from different cultures who don't really know each other.

Note: This answer was written from Middle Eastern region perspective, and might not reflect the reality of Western Academia, its principles and values. Keep this in mind.
Depending on your country, this recommendation letter might be a huge liability and will terminate your ability to get into any MSc. program permanently.
I would not use it, and I would obviously not disclose the fact that I have received confidential information in the way that you did - this might be punishable by the Ethics Tribunal (or your local equivalent).
Additionally, considering the content of the "recommendation" letter, if local Student Union/Student Association authority exists in your institution, I would anonymously report the relevant professor for providing malicious letters of recommendation - if such a mechanism exists in your country as well, do not underestimate its effectiveness; behavior like this usually costs the professor their position, though the exact consequences wary between countries. If you have this approach available, ensure that you do so anonymously and do not provide the exact text of the letter, unless you have immunity privileges by the Association for complaints (this is not necessarily the case in every country with S.A., you need to check this ahead of time).
Since many other answers touch on ethics, I also want to point out that in my country of origin writing such a recommendation letter is culturally unacceptable to the point of physical retaliation, and the letter would be revealed to the applicant during application process anyway (in my country it's required by law).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
